# Will AngularDart 5 child routes refresh the parent route

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

I have an AngularDart 5 application with the following nested component structure:

- The `mainComponent` with the main router outlet. Its path is `/`.
- Component `A` as the child of the `mainComponent`. It also has its own router outlet and its path is `/a`.
- Component `1` as a child of `A`. Its path is `/a/1`.
- Component `2` as another child of `A`. Its path is
  `/a/2`.

**Will switching from `1` to `2` trigger a reload/render of the page `a`?**

**E.g. when playing a video in `a` will switching from `1` to `2` make the video reload?**

**If so, can this be prevented?**

I´m actually asking this question because for me when switching from `1` to `2` the page will reload/rerender.

**EDIT:**

Here are my routing configurations.

Routes of the main component:

```
class AppRoutePaths {
  static final portal = RoutePath(path: 'portal');
  static final workspace = RoutePath(path: 'workspace');
}

class AppRoutes {
  static final _default = RouteDefinition.redirect(
      path: '', redirectTo: AppRoutePaths.portal.toUrl());

  static final _workspaceRoute = RouteDefinition(
      routePath: AppRoutePaths.workspace,
      component:
          workspace_component.WorkspaceComponentNgFactory as ComponentFactory);

  static final all = [_default, _workspaceRoute];
}
```

and the corresponding router outlet:

```
<router-outlet [routes]="AppRoutes.all"></router-outlet>
```

Those are the routes of component `A`:

```
class WorkspaceRoutePaths {
  static final dashboard =
      RoutePath(path: 'dashboard', parent: AppRoutePaths.workspace);

  static final settings =
      RoutePath(path: 'settings', parent: AppRoutePaths.workspace);
}

class WorkspaceRoutes {
  static final dashboard = RouteDefinition(
      routePath: WorkspaceRoutePaths.dashboard,
      component: dashboard_component_template.DashboardComponentNgFactory as ComponentFactory);

  static final settings = RouteDefinition(
      routePath: WorkspaceRoutePaths.settings,
      component: settings_component_template.SettingsComponentNgFactory as ComponentFactory);

  static final _default = RouteDefinition.redirect(
      path: '', redirectTo: WorkspaceRoutePaths.dashboard.toUrl());

  static final all = [dashboard, settings, _default];
}
```

and the corresponding router outlet:

```
<router-outlet [routes]="WorkspaceRoutes.all"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: is a router-outlet located in **A** so **1** and **2** are children of **A**?

Comment: Exactly. Will update the question.

Comment: Please provide your routes-config.

Comment: I updated the question. Please take another look. Thanks

Comment: So 'workspace' is just a logical path, does not contain a component?

Comment: Workspace component has an option to route between settings and dashboard component. Workspace component itself is a child component of my main component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a component to be reused then you need to add the [`CanReuse` mixin](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router/5#canreuse-interface) to your component.

In the case of component `A` it would look like this:

```
@Component(
    selector: "component-a",
    templateUrl: "component-a.html",
    styleUrls: ["component-a.css"],
    directives: [routerDirectives])
class A with CanReuse {...}
```